# Having some problem with getting even number output in assembly

Tags: loops, assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I took input in array. Then I tried to print the even numbers in the array. I got output as expected but I am getting extra numbers after printing the result. Like suppose my array is 1,2,3 output is

> 200000000000...

and continues.

My code:

```
include emu8086.inc

org 100h

define_scan_num
define_print_num
define_print_num_uns
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
a dw ?
b dw 50 dup(?)    
z dw ?

.code
main proc

mov ax, @data
mov ds,ax

call scan_num
printn ""

mov a,cx
mov bx,1

for1:
push cx
call scan_num
printn ""
mov b[bx],cx
add bx,2 
pop cx
loop for1

mov bx,1
mov cx,a  

for2:  
mov ax, b[bx]
mov dx,0
mov z,2
div z 
cmp dx,0  
je even
jne odd
loop for2

jmp skip

even:
mov ax,b[bx]
call print_num 
printn ""
add bx,2 
jmp for2

odd: 
add bx,2
jmp for2 

skip:
ret

main endp
end main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for2:  
> mov ax, b[bx]
> mov dx,0
> mov z,2
> div z 
> cmp dx,0  
> je even
> jne odd
> loop for2
> jmp skip
> ```

The above code is a loop that is supposed to run a limited number of times.
It doesn't, because the externally placed *even* and *odd* cases jump back to the top of the loop when they should jump back to the `loop for2` instruction for a correct loop execution.

### Some why's and an example

- Why do you divide by 2 to see if the number is even? It is enough to `test` the lowest bit. If that bit is 0 (`jz`) then the number is even, if that bit is 1 (`jnz`) then the number is odd.
- Why do you place the *even* and *odd* cases external to the loop? It's much easier if you keep those inside the loop. Less jumping around.
- Why do you duplicate code like `add bx, 2` ? Seeing that is mostly an indication of ill-structured code.
- Why do you start addressing your array of **words** at the odd offset of 1? If you decide to change this to the more sensible 0 then do it everywhere (in *for1* and in *for2*)!

An example:

```
    xor     bx, bx       ; BX=0
    mov     cx, a
for2:  
    mov     ax, b[bx]
    test    ax, 1        ; TEST does not change the value in AX ...
    jnz     odd          ; print_num can use it without reloading!
even:
    call    print_num 
    printn ""
odd:
    add     bx, 2
    dec     cx
    jnz     for2
    ret
main endp
end main
```

For better performance you can replace `loop ...` by `dec cx` `jnz ...`.

Comment: Oh i see..Thank you..I did not know the use of test..Thank you